# Scope injection like in AngularJS for more modern libraries

Tags: angular, reactjs, vue.js

I've got a entire platform written in good old AngularJS and wish to change to a more modern framework with time. But, what keeps worrying me with all this ES6, Webpack and TypeScript sugar is dynamic scope injection. Not sure I'm using the right word, but our use-case is that we've built a AngularJS app which is compiled at deployment. Then in very specific scenarios where customers need something special for a page we can today in AngularJS dynamically inject into a scope which already exists on the page and modify the scope properties. E.g. if we have a button that on click leads to page Y. We can then with JavaScript on their page dynamically inject into the button directive and overwrite scope properties to change the functionality.

Is this possible with either VueJS, React or Angular? With good old JavaScript outside the compiled package to inject into components and change their behavior? It's quite vital for us to do this, so we really don't wan't to make any mistake in choosing a wrong framework moving forward.

Use-case / Example:

Let's say our app implements a directive for a button element. This directive then on click redirects the user. Then outside the the compiled source we then in a very specific scenario want this button to do something else.

E.g.:

```
/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name el-button
 *
 * @description
 */

angular.module('el-button', [])
.directive(‘elButton’, function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    template: '<button class="el-button" ng-click="click()">Button</button>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.click = function () { window.location.href = '/some-url'; }
    }
  };
});
angular.module('someapp').requires.push('el-button');
```

We can then outside of the compiled source directly on the page change the behavior to do something else:

```
/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name custom.el-button
 *
 * @description
 */

angular.module('custom.el-button', [])
.directive(‘elButton’, function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    replace: false,
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.click = function () { alert('click'); }
    }
  };
});
angular.module('someapp').requires.push('custom.el-button');
```

In this scenario we change the behavior from redirecting the user to showing an alert.

Comment: The question is broad at this point. Providing a really short code example that describes your situation would help to keep it on-topic. It's also unclear if you use 'scope' as AngularJS term or in a broader sense.

Comment: @EstusFlask Added an example. You're right. I mean scope as in AngularJS terms. How that could apply to other frameworks is what I'm interesting in. Being able to inject into existing functionality like how we're able to do in AngularJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible with either VueJS, React or Angular? With good old JavaScript outside the compiled package to inject into components and change their behavior?

No, at least without using these frameworks outside their common

The concept of hierarchical scope (`scope` set to `true`) is specific to AngularJS. It has been superseded by isolated scope for most uses because of design reasons.

Components were introduced in AngularJS 1.5 and were supposed to smooth the transition to Angular 2.

A correct way to write `el-button` directive in all said frameworks is to represent it as a component and extend it if necessary. Their current primary use involves a build step (Webpack + Babel/TypeScript toolchain), therefore component is supposed to be extended at compilation time and not runtime (inline script).

## AngularJS (modern)

ES modules and fine-grained AngularJS modules are used together, this provides extra levels of extendability at the cost of boilerplate.

*el-button.js*

```
export class Controller {
  onClick = () => {/* general implementation */};
}

export const component = {
  template: '<button ng-click="$ctrl.onClick()">Button</button>',                                    
  controller: Controller
};

export default angular.module('namespace.el-button', []).component('elButton', component).name;
```

*general-app.js*

```
import elButtonComponentModule from './el-button';

export default angular.module('namespace.app', [elButtonComponentModule, ...]).name;
```

It's easier to do this in AngularJS than in other frameworks because it allows to override original component module with a module of the same name (`namespace.el-button`):

*my-el-button.js*

```
import { Controller as OriginalController, component as originalComponent } from './el-button';

export class Controller extends OriginalController {
  onClick = () => {/* my implementation */};
}

export const component = {
  ...originalComponent,
  controller: Controller
};

export default angular.module('namespace.el-button', []).component('elButton', component).name;
```

*my-app.js*

```
import generalAppModule from './general-app';
import myElButtonComponentModule from './my-el-button';

export default angular.module('my.app', [generalAppModule, myElButtonComponentModule]).name;
```

## Angular

Angular modules are used to register components. Duplicate selectors are not allowed, this requires to not list original component in module declarations.

*el-button.html*

```
<button (click)="onClick()">Button</button>
```

*el-button.js*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'el-button',
  templateUrl: require('./el-button.html')
})
export default class ElButton {
  onClick() {/* general implementation */}
}
```

*general-app.js*

```
import ElButton from './el-button';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ElButton, ...], ...
})
...
```

*my-el-button.js*

```
import OriginalComponent from './el-button';

@Component({
  selector: 'el-button',
  templateUrl: require('./el-button.html')
})
export class ElButton {
  onClick() {/* my implementation */}
}
```

*my-app.js*

```
import ElButton from './my-el-button';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ElButton, ...], ...
})
...
```

This may require to replace modules with custom ones at multiple levels to redefine a component from nested module and result in boilerplate.

## Vue

Vue doesn't have framework modules but provides extensibility out of the box.

*el-button.js*

```
export default Vue.component('el-button', {
  template: `<button @click="onClick">Button</button>`,
  methods: {
    onClick() {/* general implementation */}
  }
};
```

*my-el-button.js*

```
import OriginalComponent from './el-button';

export default Vue.component('el-button', OriginalComponent.extends({
  methods: {
    onClick() {/* my implementation */}
  }
};
```

Defining a component with same selector will override original component. This may become more complicated if components are registered locally.

## React

Since it's view library and not a full-blown framework, it doesn't provide anything to extend components that are already used in view. This requires to explicitly write components to use dependency injection to extend them, e.g. receive `onClick` from the outside with React context:

*el-button.jsx*

```
const ElButtonContext = React.createContext({
   onClick() {/* general implementation */}
});

const ElButton = () => {
   const { onClick } = React.useContext(ElButtonContext);
   return <button onClick={onClick}>Button</button>;
}
```

*my-app.jsx*

```
<ElButtonContext.Provider value={ onClick() {/* my implementation */} }>
  <ComponentThatUsesElButton/>
</ElButtonContext.Provider>
```

## Framework-independent module replacement

All of listed frameworks can swap dependencies at build time with a bundler; Webpack allows this with `resolve.alias` option and `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin`.

This option is specific to the environment and may be unavailable (not available by default in `create-react-app` projects) but this allows to extend components even if this isn't supported at application level, e.g. for React:

*my-el-button.jsx*

```
import OriginalComponent from '@aliased-el-button-module';

function onClick() {/* my implementation */}

const ElButton = props => {
   const el = OriginalComponent(props); // a hack that heavily depends on the implementation
   el.props.onClick = onClick;
   return el;
}
```

This may become more complicated in case a module that needs to be replaced has been already built, for instance, it belongs to third-party library.

> Is this possible with either VueJS, React or Angular? With good old JavaScript outside the compiled package to inject into components and change their behavior?

No, at least if the application has been developed with best practices suggested for these frameworks. Doing this would require to break the encapsulation provided by JS modules, pollute global scope by assigning all significant application internals to `window`:

```
const ElButton = () => {...};

const ComponentThatUsesElButton = () => (
  <window.myNamespace.ElButton /> // ugh!
);

window.myNamespace = {
  React,
  ElButton,
  ComponentThatUsesElButton,
  ...
};
```

All of these frameworks are supposed to be used with additional toolchain and don't play well with *good old JavaScript*. Angular relies on ES.next decorators and ahead-of-time compilation and has limited functionality with pure JS. Vue uses custom .vue format and has limited functionality with pure JS. React is fully functional with pure JS but more verbose and inexpressive without JSX syntax.

Comment: @xadm As I understand it, this requirement isn't carved in stone but the OP tries to estimate the feasibility of this because it's what they got accustomed to. I did my best explaining why it's a foot gun with modern frameworks and how the use case the OP described is conventionally solved there.

Answer (score 3):

"good ... Angular" :D

apples vs oranges

**Problems**

React renders view dynamically (DOM elements created/updated/removed from virtual structure), you can't (shouldn't) operate on real DOM elements as component pros/state changes are forcing rerendering, updating real DOM discarding external changes.

**Parent component can't inject anything into child to change anything** ... but can provide **props**: values and handlers/functions. Child can use them to modify behaviour. It's a **real data [and js] driven structure**, **much more flexible than in template based competitors**. *UPDATE:* **Combination of a few conditions** (if/else) **quickly becomes complicated/unreadable/duplicated** while in react it's **easy/cheap to extract/abstract using  subcomponents** [in the same file, readable, expandable]. Cheap changes - wrapping/injecting new props (other data source) is easy, too.

Child can use props not only from direct parent but also from centralized state (f.e. redux, context).

**This scenario/use case**

The same react app compiled, deployed for multiple clients (served pages) - some of them require different behaviour, without app change (recompiling).

**Solution ideas**

[IMHO] As fully data driven app there is no other way like making a config awared app with settings stored in a centralized state. New requirement, new deploying (for all), new features used only by some clients (feature toggle - by config)

- Redux (f.e.) store can be accessed from external scripts (`dispatch()`) or middleware
- initial state can be prepared/prerendered
- config can be read from API per client (or even per user - sellable feature!)
- you can block access to some features - RBAC, free/pro account etc.

## Update

As I wrote earlier react components are props driven ... using **render props** technique you can update the entire view, not only event handlers.

This way you can **replace** (runtime) **entire element with completely new** (not defined earlier) **structures**/implementation (complex view and behaviour) ... f.e. insert additional text (GDPR terms read separately from API/file) plus logic (scroll check + checkbox) required to enable submit button instead single button (for EU targets).

IMHO it (js driven composition) is a **react killer feature**.

[In oposition to @Estus] I'm almost sure that you can do these changes using complete [but customized] toolchain, **using JSX, not low level pure JS**.

*UPDATE*: I mean **you can create a plugin system**. **On demand** (2-5% customers very important requirement) - **incrementally, not ahead/overengineered for every possible places** - you're creating a new "injection point" (make component[-s] aware of possible/conditional/overwriting rendering prop, and deploy updated 'core' for all) - making an app possible to use externally provided "plugin". Plugin can be simple or complex but [IMHO should be] prepared using JSX, transpiled/build using process/tooling. This **plugin system can be used for more conditionally available features by design**, not only as customization enabler.

VanillaJS quick fixes `directly on the page` seams to me as thinking using historical possibilities like template systems, html string replacing, jQuery magic etc. while this kind of plugin system makes it much more flexible, not only browser related and [if required] can be easily ported/adopted to react native app (the same API/config consumer).

> It's quite vital for us to do this, so we really don't wan't to make any mistake in choosing a wrong framework moving forward.

You (company) should make a **proof of concept** (PoC) for this scenario [using one or more libraries]. If you're woried about step learning curve (or required knowledge) then outsource this task.

Comment: The obvious limitation of render props is that it only works when you directly control how the comp is used. Replacing deeply nested component like described in the question will require to paste and replace all component hierarchy. Unless each and every component that could be replaced was injected somehow (props, context, etc). Which is generally considered overengineering (for a good reason). As for JSX, I meant that the OP can't use it for a quickfix with vanilla JS `outside of the compiled source directly on the page`, at least without client-side Babel (which isn't very good for prod).